# ASP.NET проблемы с кириллицей внутри тега script

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Создадим строку с русскими символами в любом View

```
@{
    var str = "Привет, мир!";
}
```

Попытаемся вывести ее внутри тега script

```
<script>
    @str
</script>
```

Используя инструменты разработчика в браузере, смотрим разметку страницы и видим следующее

```
<script>
    &#x41F;&#x440;&#x438;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442;, &#x43C;&#x438;&#x440;!
</script>
```

Я использую ASP.NET Core 2.1. Мне нужно было вызвать функцию JS и передать ей строку, содержащую русские символы. Строка заранее неизвестна. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: У вас в HTML есть тег `<meta charset="...">` с нужной кодировкой? Так же, можно проверить кодировку самого файла.

Comment: В HTML `<meta charset="utf-8" />`, все файлы сохранены в кодировке UTF-8, проверял в Notepad++

Comment: Попробуйте поменять на `@(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(str))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы избежать экранирования при вставке символов в HTML, нужно вместо обычной строки использовать [HtmlString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.html.htmlstring?view=aspnetcore-2.0):

```
@(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(str))
```